# Animation time of UICollectionView on deletion of cell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using collection view for the very first time i need to delete the cell of the collection view on click.which is working properly for me.But i am struggling  with the animation time of UIcollectionview .It is always same .How can i increase or decrease the  animation time on deletion of the cell.I am also putting that code in uianimation block but it is not working .
Here is my code on deletion,any advise would be highly appreciated thanks.

```
  [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
  NSArray* itemPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
  // Delete the items from the data source.
  [self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:itemPaths];
  // Now delete the items from the collection view.
  [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:tempArray
  } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in the above delegate method, do the following:

```
NSIndexPath *lIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:lIndexPath];

//Perform flip animation
//_AnimationDuration defined in Constant.h
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:_AnimationDuration];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];

//Implementation of GCD to delete a flip item
double delay = _AnimationDuration/2;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
    [self deleteContent:indexPath];
});


-(void) deleteContent:(NSIndexPath *)_indexPath{

//Remove items from array on delete
    [itemArr removeObjectAtIndex:_indexPath.row];

//Reload the items of UICollectionView performBatchUpdates Block
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[_indexPath]];
    } completion:nil];


}
```