# Swipe Animation for remove Cell in UICollectionView - Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created an app with `UICollectionView` like this image:

[image]

Added two gestures:

The first (up) will erase the cell.

The second (down) will update the cell (take new data of CoreData).
The functions work fine, but there's no animation. iOS has a very cool animation dragging the cell up and the cell disappears.

I am a beginner in animations swift, so I'm a little lost when it.

My question is: How can I add an animation that takes up the entire cell?

I read some answers on the site, but all in Object-C ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742677/animation-time-of-uicollectionview-on-deletion-of-cell-in-ios)).

Can someone help me?

Comment: James your app looks great!

Comment: James, did you ever get this working as you intended? Looking to implement exactly the same type of functionality in Swift. Would love to see your app, if working too!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to achieve the animation on the cell of `UICollectionView` is overriding its layout `UICollectionViewLayout`. Its has method which will return the layout attributes of the cell which you want to either appear/insert/delete.

For example: I created a class `KDCollectionViewFlowLayout` inheriting `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override the delete attribute.

```
class KDCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath)

        attribute?.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(attributes.transform, 0, ITEM_SIZE)
        attribute?.alpha = 0.0
        return attribute

    }
}
```

Now you need to assign object of this flowLayout to the collection view in either viewDidLoad or you can assign it through storyboard.

```
let flowLayout = KDCollectionViewFlowLayout()
self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
```

Now, you are all set for transformation of cell which you defined in to `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath` method whenever you perform any delete operation on the `collectionView`.

**Update**

You need delete the items from collection view using batch operation.

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
   //Array of the data which you need to deleted from collection view
    let indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
    //Delete those entery from the data base. 

    //TODO: Delete the information from database

    //Now Delete those row from collection View 

    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)

}, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Right, in the first instance, I tried to fit in my code, but did not succeed. My code is divided into three: A class and two extensions.

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DHIQE.png)

How do I fit his example in my code? I'm more confused than initially ...

Comment: Excuse me, but have not worked here, you could post a link to download your example, for me to see in practice how you organized everything?

Comment: @James, Perfect [sample code](https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout) for deletion animation.