# Swipe Animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swipe

I added two gestures lead to cell `UICollectionView` up and down.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell

    cell.card = self.cards[indexPath.item]

    let UpSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("gestureToUp:"))
    UpSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(UpSwipe)

    let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("gestureToDown:"))
    downSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)


    return cell
}
func gestureToUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("up")
}

func gestureToDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("down")
}
```

I would like to add a animation equal to swipe to delete the email app.
I tried to do something equal to `UITableViewController`, but it seems that is not allowed, and the articles I read about it, do not show anything about the cell of `UICollectionView`.

Some can help me?

Comment: You need to override `UICollectionViewLayout ` of the collectionView to get the animation effect on deletion of the cell. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294864/swipe-animation-for-remove-cell-in-uicollectionview-swift-2-0) is sample for adding animation on cell.