# Reload Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uicollectionview

I have collectionview with cells that displays data from a SQLite database. I also have a button that deletes rows from the SQLite database. I would like to refresh the collectonview and remove the cells that no longer contain the deleted row but my snippet below isn't working, the row gets deleted from the SQLite db but the view isn't refreshed unless I leave that view and come back to it.

```
    @IBAction func buttonViewHeartAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonViewHeartAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true
            ).first!
        let db = try! Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
        let table = Table("coffee_table")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
        let name = Expression<String>("name")
        let url = Expression<String>("url")
        let alice = table.filter(url == face.directLink)
        try! db.run(alice.delete())
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.collectionview.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    @IBAction func buttonViewHeartAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonViewHeartAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true
            ).first!
        let db = try! Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
        let table = Table("coffee_table")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
        let name = Expression<String>("name")
        let url = Expression<String>("url")
        let alice = table.filter(url == face.directLink)
        try! db.run(alice.delete())
        var newfaces = [face]
        self.faces = newfaces
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.collectionview.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

**Edit 3:**

```
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true
        ).first!
    let db = try! Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
    let table = Table("coffee_table")
    let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
    let name = Expression<String>("name")
    let url = Expression<String>("url")

    var newfaces=[face]()

    for tables in try! db.prepare(table) {
        //getting the data at each index
        let coffeefaceName = (tables[name]) as! String
        let coffeefaceDirectLink = (tables[url]) as! String
        let coffeefaceImage = (tables[url]) as! String

        let newface = face(name:coffeefaceName,
                           directLink: coffeefaceDirectLink,
                           image:coffeefaceImage)
        newfaces.append(newface)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.faces = newfaces
        self.collectionview.reloadData()
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have updated your collectionview data array properly after the deletion?

Comment: I think so. I mean if I leave the view and come back to the collection view the deleted data is no longer displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably haven't updated your data array after the deletion. So before you do

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     self.collectionview.reloadData()
})
```

Make sure to do something like

```
yourArray = sqldata
```

Where `yourArray` is the array that you use to populate your `colelctionView` and `sqldata` is the data from the database.

**Edit**

So remove the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     self.collectionview.reloadData()
})
```

and replace it with this `getDataAndReloadCollectionView()` and create a function

```
func getDataAndReloadCollectionView(){
    var newfaces=[face]()
    for tables in try! db.prepare(table) {
        //getting the data at each index
        let coffeefaceName = (tables[name]) as! String
        let coffeefaceDirectLink = (tables[url]) as! String
        let coffeefaceImage = (tables[url]) as! String

        let newface = face(name:coffeefaceName,
                           directLink: coffeefaceDirectLink,
                           image:coffeefaceImage)
        newfaces.append(newface)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.faces = newfaces
        self.collectionview.reloadData()
    })
}
```

So basically create a new function that will get the new data, call this function whenever you want to get data and reload your collectionView

Comment: Thanks Rashwan, I did as you suggested but I'm not quite there yet. Please see my edit for the 2 lines I added as you suggested. What happens now is that the collection view does refresh when I click on the delete button but it only displays the deleted row data upon refresh. When I leave the view and come back to it it does not display the deleted row and only displays the rows that are there, as it should.

Comment: When you load the viewController you do set the faces array can you show me that row.

Comment: Worked like a charm after some very minor additions, thank you Rashwan.

Is there a way to animate the deletion of cells? As it stands it's very instant deletion but I would like to animate the cells.. Android has built-in features for this, does Swift?

Comment: Np, glad to help. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294864/swipe-animation-for-remove-cell-in-uicollectionview-swift-2-0) post for animation on deletion.