# Updating UICollectionView based on Array Comparison

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I currently have a `collectionView: UICollectionView` that displays contents based on an array of objects called `projects`. At times I will receive an updated array called `newProjects` from a server. `newProjects` should replace `projects` as the data source for the `collectionView`.

I have figured out a way to update the `collectionView` when objects have been deleted from the array with the following code:

```
var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

for project in projects {

    if(!newProjects.contains(project)) {

        let index = projects.firstIndex(of: project)
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: index!, section: 0))
    }                      
}

collectionView.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)

projects = newProjects
collectionView.reloadData()
```

This works for deleted projects. However, I am also trying to react to added projects. My code however seems to fail, since I keep getting the exception:

> Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (65) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (64), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

My code for added project comparison is:

```
// First, the deletion from the code above is called.
// project = newProjects and data reload doesn't happen after deletion.

var addIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

for project in newProjects {

    if(!projects.contains(project)) {

        projects.append(content)
        addIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: projects.count - 1, section: 0))
    }
}

collectionView.insertItems(at: addIndexPaths)

projects = newProject 
collectionView.reloadData()
```

I'm sure this code is somewhat of a hack job (since it doesn't function), but I honestly can't figure out how else to reliably update a `UICollectionView`. Does anyone have suggestions or helpful links? Cheers!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just update the main datasource and reload the collection view?- Can you show the code for your network call and your cellForItemAtIndexPath please :)

Comment: Hey Wez, thanks for your comment. Me not reloading the entire collection view was a remnant of me thinking it wouldn't work due to prior problems with the whole system. Actually taking out all the insertion and addition of items and just calling `reloadData()` did end up working.

Comment: Never call both `deleteItems/insertItems` and `reloadData` together. Only use one or the other at any given time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload Collection View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456904/reload-collection-view)

Comment: Thanks for your help @rmaddy, that approach also works.

Comment: @Wez might be, however I believe it might be useful to know that `deleteItems` and `insertItems` don't work with `reloadData`, as @rmaddy pointed out. In that case it's probably a bit different to your linked question. But I don't really think that's for me to decide

Answer (score 0):

As [Wez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757214/wez) pointed out, just taking out all the insertion and deletion of data did end up working. Now the entirety of the call is just reduced to:

```
projects = newProjects
collectionView.reloadData()
```

I initially thought that didn't work, but that was due to a problem with the server. I hadn't tried it yet, thinking I needed to manually insert all changed projects.

As [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) pointed out, taking `reloadData()` out of the original code also worked! My initial thought for some reason was that `reloadData()` would be necessary after adding and deleting items, probably because I also thought `UITableViews` required you to call `endUpdates()`... I overcomplicated some essential concepts.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: No, table views do not require a call to `endUpdates`. `begin/endUpdates` are only required under specific circumstances. And a single to call to `delete/insert/reloadItems` or `reloadData` is not one of them.